# Automating a pipeline that converts float values into integer values

Tags: python

I am working with the Kaggle competition data from House Prices. I am simply trying to transform all columns that have float values to integers. The code shows some cleaning and then it shows what I am trying to do. There really is only one column that has float values but this is part of a pipeline so I am trying to get an automated way to basically grab float values in a dataframe and spit them back as integer values in the right place. I have been trying for two days but cannot crack it! The code below doesn't do anything... it doesn't change the values. The code that is commented out neither works as it spits the error: *AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'append'*

This is how the series look like:

```
0       2003.0
1       1976.0
2       2001.0
3       1998.0
4       2000.0
         ...  
1454    2004.0
1455    1999.0
1456    1978.0
1457    1941.0
1458    1950.0
Name: GarageYrBlt, Length: 1459, dtype: float64
```

Here's the code I am trying:

```
# Sorts out na values
for col in none_cols:
    data[col].fillna('None', inplace=True)
for col in zero_cols:
    data[col].fillna(0, inplace=True)
for col in mode_cols:
    data[col].fillna(data[col].mode()[0], inplace=True)

# Sorts out categorical and numerical columns
lc_cat_cols = [ccol for ccol in data.columns if data[ccol].nunique() < 10 and data[ccol].dtype == 'object']
int_cols = [ncol for ncol in X.columns if X[ncol].dtype  == 'int64']
for col, colSeries in data.iteritems():
    if colSeries.dtype == 'float64':
        for k, v in colSeries.iteritems():
            colSeries[k] = v
            #colSeries[k].append(int(v))
```

Comment: have you tried: df.column_name.astype(int) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
for i in df.columns:
    if df.dtypes[i]=='float64':
        df[i]=df[i].astype(int)
```